# android facebook sdk after add library

Tags: java, android

I click on My Project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library
and get an error (which worked before I performed "Add Support Library")

I think that I have an issue with the Facebook SDK:

This is part of my `mainActivity`:

```
Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }
```

In the line:

```
session.openForRead(**new Session.OpenRequest(this)**.setCallback(statusCallback));
```

it gives me an error:

> The type android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be resolved. It is
>   indirectly referenced from   required .class files

Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: have u triedsomething like this:
`openReq = new Session.OpenRequest(this);`
`openReq.setCallback(statusCallback);`
`session.openForRead(openReq);`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved checking Android Private Libraries in Build Path -> Order and Export of My Project, Facebook-SDK Project and Other Project Linked

[Checking Android Private Libraries](https://plus.google.com/photos/117122118961369445953/albums/5878509263473846433/5878509268379848162)

[From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602584/error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-content-localbroadcas)

Answer (score -1):

Last time when I tried using the "Add Support Library" function, the console kept saying "Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list"

Check your project's libs folder and remove android-support-v4.jar if it's there, it is because Facebook SDK already include that library.

See if it helps.