# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: GCMIntentService

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gae-eclipse-plugin

My app used to work perfectly fine. Recently I updated eclipse (the plugins), and now I am getting this error. I have not changed my code so I know it should continue to work. but it does not. I am using the google eclipse plugin, which the updates changed to version 8.

Basically I still see everything in the android project. the `gcm.jar` is still there for example. And my manifest has not change. I can keep listing stuff but it would just be more words. Bottom line: It used to work fine.

Comment: what did you update and to which version? This info might help. You might have tried removing ti from your build path and adding it again. Also its in `libs` folder right?

Comment: I updated everything that had an available update. Included were android and app engine. For android I had a few updates

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Comment: Before voting to close as duplicate: I am now getting this new error after checking the private library: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding to @athor's answer, as you said that you updated everything. Its a high possibility that you updated android SDK-tools to latest version 22. This is a known issue and this has been discussed many times. You might want to check out following threads and [picture](https://plus.google.com/photos/117122118961369445953/albums/5878509263473846433/5878509268379848162?pid=5878509268379848162&oid=117122118961369445953).

[Android app crashes after SDK-tools update version (NoClassDefFound, tool version 22)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589821/android-app-crashes-after-sdk-tools-update-version-noclassdeffound-tool-versio)

[ERROR : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602584/error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-content-localbroadcas)

The picture and thread will help to find the exact location where to make changes. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Now I am getting this new error: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf`

Comment: Make sure you've done the same for all the libraries that you've included in your project. Are you using emulator to test? If yes make sure it supports Google API's

Comment: For some reason I had to also click on `add support library`. It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

In the new adt tools, you need to tick the checkbox for Android Private Libraries in the Java Build Path for your project.

Comment: Where in eclipse do I find that?

Comment: Thanks for helping. +1. The other answer gave me a bit more in the right direction.