# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with GCM Service

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get GCM running on my Android-App, I am getting this strange error message a short while after GCMRegistrar.register() was called ( app-name is the name of the app I can't disclose):

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
 "com.<companyname>.<appname>.GCMIntentService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
 "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/<app-
 name>"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/<app.name>, 
 /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

The (I think) relevant part of AndroidManifest:

```
 <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

The class GCMIntentService exists at the specified path, I copied the file from the GCM-Client project provided  by Google, so I don't really get what the problem is.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I moved the class GCMIntentService to the following package:

```
 com.google.android.gcm.demo.app
```

No I get a warning:

```
Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION 
flg=0x10 pkg=com.<company-name>.<app-name> 
cmp=com.xitaso.plugsurfing/.GCMIntentService (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

What does that mean?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: @Thomas Bouron I am using Eclipse.

Comment: Make sure package name is correct.

Comment: @deimos1988 Go to Project settings -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export and make sure that `Android private libraries` is checked.

Comment: @Thomas Bouron Private libraries are checked.

Comment: @Dhaval Package name should be correct, if there's an error, I don't know where.

Comment: Update Logcat in your question

Comment: @Dhaval Logcat doesn't really say any more than what I've already posted :)

Comment: Is your service registered in manifest file?

Comment: The only possible explanation I see is that the package name within your `AndroidManifest.xml` is wrong or your file `GCMIntentService.java` is not within this package.

Comment: @ThomasBouron is possibly correct. You should re-check. Possibly manifest entry is wrong. Also make sure Broadcast receiver is registered as well.

Comment: Have a go at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035344/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-gcmintentservice

Comment: @Dhaval I haven't updated update my SDK Toolkit, so unfortunately that doesn't help :)

Comment: @Thomas Bouron I think so, too, but I really don't know what it is :(

Comment: try to specify the package name for the intent service <service android:name="packagename.GcmIntentService" /> i think you have it in a   different package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was: The GCMIntentService had to be in the root of the package name, in my case in com.companyname.appname; I created a separate package where I put the GCMIntentService-class, and it worked fine from then on (at least I think that that was the main problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use GCM and this exception comes from other library just do this:

```
 <service
     android:name="package.GCMIntentService"
     tools:node="remove" />
```